# Another case of which compiler is right

Tags: c++, visual-c++, language-lawyer

In my endless pursuit of happiness I came across something like this

```
auto temp = new int;
delete[0] temp;
```

and in my mind I was like... *"This can't be right !"* so I fired up the most special and rebellious snowflake compiler to test it and, lo and behold, it compiled and ran without any issues !

I then tried it in GCC (4.8.1) and it rejected it with this error

> error: expected ‘]’ before numeric constant

So I ask you my fellow comrades, which one is right? ( surely not MSVC(11) ?! ) and if you could quote the standard that would be great.

Comment: You have a very strange idea of "happiness".

Comment: `delete[0]` - that's the first time I see that.

Comment: @nijansen: I'm weird like that

Comment: @LuchianGrigore You've not been around long enough.  When I first learned C++, not having to specify the number of elements in the delete was a new feature, and all compilers allowed you to do things the old way, and specify.  (Of course, even back then, there was _never_ any use for `new[]` and `delete[]`.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Back toward the dawn of C++, when you deleted an array you were required to specify the size of the array you'd allocated:

```
int * x = new int[10];
// ...
delete [10] x;
```

This led to many problems, so the requirement was eliminated long ago. By the time the first C++ standard was written, this syntax was no longer officially allowed.

Nonetheless, many compilers still accept this syntax for the sake of compatibility with older code that uses it. With MS VC++, this is accepted by default, but if you ask for standard compliance (-Za) you'll get an error like:

```
error C2203: delete operator cannot specify bounds for an array
```

Obligatory aside: you shouldn't be using `new` to allocate an array anyway. Use `std::vector`.

Comment: This looks fine, but it's still not very clear to me how could you call `delete[0]`. What's the meaning of a zero-size array?

Comment: @DarioP: As a transition measure, compilers often accepted a number in the brackets, but ignored it completely (and I'd guess that's what VC++ does in this case).

Comment: Re your last paragraph: he didn't use `new` to allocate an array.  He's mismatching `new` with `delete[]`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yes, I realize what he did, but based on the use of `[]` in the `delete`, I guessed that he intended to allocate an array.

Answer (score 5):

`delete[0]` is illegal syntax according to the current standard..

Plus, when you allocate an object with `new`, you should deallocate it with `delete`, and `new []` with `delete []`. They are not supposed to be interchangeable.

> #### C++11 §5.3.5 Delete
>
> The delete-expression operator destroys a most derived object (1.8) or array created by a new-expression.
>
> delete-expression:
>
> ```
> ::opt delete cast-expression
>
> ::opt delete [ ] cast-expression
> ```
>
> The first alternative is for non-array objects, and the second is for arrays. The operand shall have a pointer type, or a class type having a single conversion function (12.3.2) to a pointer type. The result has type `void`.

Answer (score 3):

The standard knows of two different types of storage deallocation, single-object form storage deallocation, 18.6.1.1/10-19, which is

```
void operator delete(void * ptr) noexcept;
void operator delete(void * ptr, std::nothrow_t const &) noexcept;
```

and array form storage deallocation, 18.6.1.2/9-17, which is

```
void operator delete[](void * ptr) noexcept;
void operator delete[](void * ptr, std::nothrow_t const &) noexcept;
```

However, historically (pre-standard) there was a `delete[N]` deallocator, that required you to deallocate as much as you had allocated for your array. I suspect that is what your compiler is interpreting.

Answer (score 0):

It ran without issues because you were lucky. Generally allocating with new and deleting with delete[] is Undefined Behaviour and "running without any issues" belongs to the set of behaviours allowed by UB. A code like this sometimes runs fine in tests but breaks at the most unexpected moment, e.g. live demo for your most important customer.